# Integral of matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definite-integrals, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Then the solution of the initial value problem
\begin{align*}
  \dot{x}(t) = A x(t), \quad x(0) = x_0
\end{align*}
is given by $x(t) = \mathrm{e}^{At} x_0$.

I am interested in the following matrix
\begin{align*}
   \int_{0}^T \mathrm{e}^{At}\, dt
\end{align*}
for some $T>0$. Can one write down a general solution to this without distinguishing cases (e.g. $A$ nonsingular)?

Is this matrix always invertible?

Comment: you can represent matrix exponential by power series

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: Spectral theorem says that if you take analytical function $f$, apply it to the matrix $A$ (its eigenvaules has to be in the domain of analaticity of $f$), then eigenvalues of $f(A)$ are $f(\text{eigenvalues of } A)$. Exponent is never zero, hence $\exp(A)$ is always invertible, moreover, $\exp(A)^{-1}=\exp(-A)$.

Answer (score 29):

**Case I.** If $A$ is nonsingular, then
$$
\int_0^T\mathrm{e}^{tA}\,dt=\big(\mathrm{e}^{TA}-I\big)A^{-1},
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

**Case II.** If $A$ is singular, then using the Jordan form we can write $A$ as
$$
A=U^{-1}\left(\begin{matrix}B&0\\0&C\end{matrix}\right)U, 
$$
where $C$ is nonsingular, and $B$ is strictly upper triangular. Then
$$
\mathrm{e}^{tA}=U^{-1}\left(\begin{matrix}\mathrm{e}^{tB}&0\\0&\mathrm{e}^{tC}
\end{matrix}\right)U,
$$
and
$$
\int_0^T\mathrm{e}^{tA}\,dt=U^{-1}\left(\begin{matrix}\int_0^T\mathrm{e}^{tB}dt&0\\0&C^{-1}\big(\mathrm{e}^{TC}-I\big)
\end{matrix}\right)U
$$
But $\int_0^T\mathrm{e}^{tB}dt$ may have different expressions. For example if
$$
B_1=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right), \quad
B_2=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right),
$$
then
$$
\int_0^T\mathrm{e}^{tB_1}dt=\left(\begin{matrix}T&0\\0&T\end{matrix}\right), \quad
\int_0^T\mathrm{e}^{tB_2}dt=\left(\begin{matrix}T&T^2/2\\0&T\end{matrix}\right).
$$

Comment: What we will do if we use   $A(t)$ instead of $tA$

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @ Yiorgos S. Smyrlis So you are saying even if $A(t)$ and $A^{'}(t)$ are not commutative,this will work

Comment: Here A is not a constant matrix. It is a variable matrix

Comment: I am talking about $\int e^{A(t)} \ dt$

Comment: If $A$ is a psd matrix, can we say $\int_0^T e^{tA}\,dt = (e^{TA}-I)A^\dagger$, where $A^\dagger$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $A$ ?

Answer (score 25):

The general formula is the power series

$$ \int_0^T e^{At} dt = T \left( I + \frac{AT}{2!} + \frac{(AT)^2}{3!} + \dots + \frac{(AT)^{n-1}}{n!} + \dots \right) $$

Note that also

$$ \left(\int_0^T e^{At} dt \right) A + I = e^{AT} $$

is always satisfied.

A sufficient condition for this matrix to be non-singular is the so-called Kalman-Ho-Narendra Theorem, which states that the matrix $\int_0^T e^{At} dt$ is invertible if

$$ T(\mu - \lambda) \neq 2k \pi i $$

for any nonzero integer $k$, where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are any pair of eigenvalues of $A$.

Note to the interested: This matrix also comes from the discretization of a continuous linear time invariant system. It can also be said that controllability is preserved under discretization if and only if this matrix has an inverse.

Comment: Thank you. This answer looks very promising. Btw, I am looking at this matrix exactly because of what you said about the discretization!

Comment: I just want to know what's the reference book or paper for Yiorgios or Obareey?

Comment: You can finish the answer by writing the integral equals $A^{-1}(e^{AT}-I)$

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ yes, this works when $A$ is invertible. The answer does not make this assumption.

Answer (score 10):

The way I like to do it is based on the following observation: let
$$ \bar{A} := 
     \begin{bmatrix} 
        A & B \\
        0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}, $$

where $0$ is the zero matrix (dimensions s.t. $\bar{A}$ is square). Then,
$$ \mathrm{e}^{\bar{A}t} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm{e}^{At} & \int_0^t\mathrm{e}^{A\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau B \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}. $$

Hence, for the integral you can just build this block matrix with $B=I$, compute the matrix exponential of it, then extract the top right block. In a more "closed" form:
$$ \int_0^t\mathrm{e}^{A\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau B = \begin{bmatrix}I & 0\end{bmatrix}\mathrm{e}^{\bar{A}t}\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ I\end{bmatrix}. $$

The advantage of this method with respect to using matrix inversion and/or Jordan form is that this method is numerically stable even when $A$ is singular (or close to singular). The disadvantage, of course, is that it takes a 4x bigger matrix as an input.

#### Why it works

It follows from this observation: if you have the non-homogeneous ODE
$$ \dot{X}(t) = AX(t) + B, $$
its solution is
$$ X(t) = \mathrm{e}^{At}X(0) +  \int_0^t\mathrm{e}^{A\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau B. $$

Define the auxiliary variable $U(t)$, which is constant (i.e., $U(t) = U(0)$ for all positive $t$). Then $\dot{U}(t) = 0$ and we have the system of ODEs
\begin{align*}
\dot{X}(t) &= AX(t) + BU(t), \\
\dot{U}(t) &= 0,
\end{align*}

which is a homogeneous ODE on the augmented variable $\begin{bmatrix} X(t) \\ U(t) \end{bmatrix}$. Therefore, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} \dot{X}(t) \\ \dot{U}(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
        A & B \\
        0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} {X}(t) \\ {U}(t) \end{bmatrix} = \bar{A}\begin{bmatrix} {X}(t) \\ {U}(t) \end{bmatrix}$$
whose solution is
$$\begin{bmatrix} {X}(t) \\ {U}(t) \end{bmatrix} = \mathrm{e}^{\bar{A}t}\begin{bmatrix} {X}(0) \\ {U}(0) \end{bmatrix},$$

but also,

$$\begin{bmatrix} {X}(t) \\ {U}(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm{e}^{At}X(0) +  \int_0^t\mathrm{e}^{A\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau BU(0) \\ U(0) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm{e}^{At} &  \int_0^t\mathrm{e}^{A\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau B \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} X(0) \\ U(0) \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Very nice implementation and explanation.

Comment: +1  Very nice explanation.

Comment: What would happen if you multiplied out the vectors?

Answer (score 3):

### A Python numerical answer

It is surprisingly *difficult* to find a proper python package for numerical integration of matrix. I know it is not what the question want but I cannot find anywhere else to publish this.

Here, I provide a numerical solution to it. Just call the function

```
intergral_result = compute_exp_matrix_intergration(A,T)
```

will be enough

```
import numpy as np
def compute_exp_matrix_intergration(A,T,nbins=100):
    f = lambda x: expm(A*x)
    xv = np.linspace(0,T,nbins)
    result = np.apply_along_axis(f,0,xv.reshape(1,-1))
    return np.trapz(result,xv)
```

Comment: I get a shape error in `result = ... `. Also, to whoever it may help: the `expm` is from `scipy.linalg`.

Answer (score 1):

## Another Python implementation

Here is another implementation in Python, if it can be helpful to anyone... (and since ArtificiallyIntelligence's answer returns an error in my setup).
The value of the integral is `integral` and the last line verifies the equality $\int_0^T e^{At}dt = A^{-1}(e^{tA}-I)$, provided $A$ is nonsingular (which is generically the case for randomly generated matrices).

```
import numpy as np
N = 5
t = 1
A = np.random.rand(N,N)
taylor = t*np.array([np.linalg.matrix_power(A*t,k)/np.math.factorial(k+1) for k in range(50)])
integral = taylor.sum(axis = 0)

print np.linalg.norm(integral - np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A),scipy.linalg.expm(t*A)-np.identity(N)))
```

Note that you should adjust the `50` in `taylor = ...` to check convergence.