# $\int_0^t e^{sA}\cos(\omega s)ds$ with $A$ matrix

Tags: calculus, integration, matrix-equations, matrix-exponential

Let $A$ be a singular square matrix and $\omega,t\in\mathbb{R}^{*+}$. How to compute the following integral?

$$I = \int_0^t e^{sA}\cos(\omega s)\,\mathrm{d}s$$

Since I am looking for a numerical solutions, I am open to approximations. For example, 
$$ I = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^t \dfrac{(sA)^k}{k!} \cos(\omega s)\,\mathrm{d}s = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{A^k}{k!}\int_0^t s^k \cos(\omega s)\,\mathrm{d}s$$

so I can truncate the above sum but I'm wondering if there is a more ingenious approach.

Comment: Complex-exponential form of $\cos$?..

Comment: @metamorphy I thought of it but I  am stuck with $e^{sA}e^{i\omega s}$ since it does not equal $e^{sA+i\omega s}$.

Comment: Well, $e^X e^Y=e^{X+Y}$ for *commuting* matrices $X, Y$. So if your $\omega$ is just a scalar, then $e^{sA} e^{i\omega s}=e^{s(A+i\omega I)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @metamorphy in the comments, it suffices to write

$$ I = \operatorname{Re}\left(\int_0^t e^{s(A+i\omega I_n)}\,\mathrm{d}s\right)$$
and the computation boils down to the integral of a matrix exponential as addressed [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658276/integral-of-matrix-exponential).